# Show that $ \ x_1, \cdots \cdots , x_n \ $ are linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $ \ x_1, \cdots \cdots , x_n \ $ are linearly Independent in a vector space $V$ if and only if $$ span \{x_1, \cdots,\hat x_i, \cdots ,x_n\} \neq span \{x_1, \cdots \cdots ,x_n \}$$ for all $i=1,2,.....,n$.

**Answer:**

Let $x_1, \cdots \cdots , x_n $ are linearly Independent.

Then $span \{x_1, \cdots , x_n \}$ generates $ V$.

So any span of these independent vectors will be same.

How to show that $ span \{x_1, \cdots,\hat x_i, \cdots ,x_n\} \neq span \{x_1, \cdots \cdots ,x_n \}$ for all $i=1,2,.....,n$ ?

Help me

Comment: If $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are l.i. in $V$, the span does not necessarily span $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the removal of a vector from the set yields the same span.

After a reordering, it's not restrictive to assume that
$$
\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}=
\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n\}
$$
which implies $x_n$ is a linear combination of $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ and therefore the set $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n\}$ is linearly dependent.

For the converse, if $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is linearly independent, then each removal yields an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use contrapositive: show that if $\;\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n\}=\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\dots,\hat{x}_i,\dots,x_n\}$ for some $i$, the vectors are not linearly independent.

Comment: how to show that the vectors are not L.I. ?

Comment: What can you deduce from the fact that  $x_i\in\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\dots,\hat x_i,\dots, x_n\}$?